# Unable to show appropriate Popup message when mouse is over WPF Radio button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two radio buttons (RadioButton1 and RadioButton2).
I need to display appropriate popup message when mouse is over one of the radio button. Hence I have following requirements

- Requirement 1: When mouse is over  "Radio Button 1" pop up message should be "Radio Button 1 is clicked". Similarly when mouse is over  "Radio Button 2" pop up message should be "Radio Button 2 is clicked" .
- Requirement 2: When mouse is clicked outside pop up control, pop up should close.
- Requirement 3: Pop up also has hyperlink that displays a webpage when clicked. for this reason it should stay open.

To fulfill above requirements, i have used WPF pop up control with following settings

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Bottom"  >
  <TextBlock  Text="{Binding RadioButtonContent, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

IsPopupOpen & RadioButtonContent are MVVM ViewModel properties that are updated when "MouseEnter" (used interaction trigger)event happens on one of radio button.

However i have encountered following issue.

When moving mouse from Radio Button 1 (at this time pop up is opened to Radio Button2, Pop up does not show "Radio Button 2 is clicked". It still shows "Radio Button 1 is clicked "!!!.

After reading the documentation for Popup in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview?view=netframework-4.8#open-and-close-behavior), i found the this is the correct behaviour, since whenever pop is opened, Mouse capture is with pop up content (TextBlock in this case). Hence "MouseEnter" event for RadioButton2 is not fired, even though mouse is over Radiobutton 2.

Note: I cannot make  StaysOpen="True" since it will not close clicking outside pop up parent. (Requirement 2 fails)
I cannot use controls like "Tooltip" or "adorner" since it wont stay. (requirement 3 fails)

How can i satisfy all 3 requirements?

Comment: You have to use the `Popup` and add a `TextBlock` which contains a [`Hyperlink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.hyperlink?view=netframework-4.8#examples) as its child element. Then use an `EventTrigger` that triggers on `RadioButton.MouseEnter` and animate the `Popup.IsOpen` property to show the `Popup`.

Comment: Hi  BionicCode, Thank you. I did those things. But my requirement is when i move my mouse from Radio button 1 to radio button 2, i should get pop up for radio button 2. This does not happen because when mouse is over Radio button 1, pop up content is displayed as "radio Button 1 is clicked". Pop up stays open and has  mouse capture. So when mouse is over "radio button 2" mouse enter for radio button is not triggered (since mouse capture is still with pop content !!!)

Comment: If you could include a picture or two and probably some XAML code that would be helpful

Comment: <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Bottom"  >
      <TextBlock  Text="{Binding RadioButtonContent, Mode=OneWay}" />
  </Popup>

IsPopupOpen & RadioButtonContent are MVVM ViewModel properties that are updated when "MouseEnter" (used interaction trigger)event happens on one of radio button.

Comment: So, create two `Popup` elements (one for each `RadioButton`). On `RadioButton.MouseEnter` always close the other popup(s) by animating `Popup.IsOpen` to `False`. During the same animation timeline show the current `Popup`. This way they will behave mutual exclusive.

Comment: Hi BionicCode, Thank you. I tried that also. but it will not help.  what i want is, when mouse is moved over another radio button(from radio button 1 to radio button 2),RadioButton.MouseEnter event to fire. Unfortunately RadioButton.MouseEnter does not fire. Instead TextBlock.MouseEnter event fires. This is expected behaviour as per MSDN documentation for Popup [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview?view=netframework-4.8#open-and-close-behavior).  Can i override this behaviour ? Or how should i release mouse capture from pop up content ?

Comment: Why popup? Have you considered using a contextmenu or tooltip rather than a popup? A tooltip will only stay open a while but this is usually considered a plus. A contextmenu closes when you click anywhere else outside it.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to set the `Popup.StaysOpen` property to `True` (which is the default value). Now that the `Popup` doesn't close automatically, you have to do it manually. To implement the default behavior (`Popup` closes when clicked somewhere in the window), you should add the required `EventTrigger` and handle e.g., `FrameworkElement.PreviewMouseUp` on `Window` level (or the appropriate focus scope).

The following example shows a `Popup` when the `RadioButton` raises the `FrameworkElement.MouseEnter` event. Each `RadioButton` has a dedicated `Popup`. Before this `Popup` displays, all other `Popup` tool tips are closed. Once the `Popup` or any other control (regarding the scope of the `EventTrigger`) raises the `FrameworkElement.PreviewMouseUp` event, the opened `Popup` will be closed. With this configuration the `Popup` is allowed to receive only a single click (e.g. `Button`).
To allow the `Popup` to stay open if a child element received a mouse click, you could handle `Popup.PreviewMouseUp` events with a dedicated `EventTrigger` which sets `Popup.IsOpen` to `True` (to override the `Popup` close `EventTrigger`). For a more complex behavior I recommend to implement an Attached Behavior.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="Window"
        Width="800"
        Height="600">

  <StackPanel>
    <Popup x:Name="ToolTip1"
           StaysOpen="True"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton1}">
      <Border Background="Transparent">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="Click to navigate to external content1" />
          <Button Content="Link" 
                  Command="{Binding NavigateToUrlCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="https://stackoverflow.com" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </Popup>
    <Popup x:Name="ToolTip2"
           StaysOpen="True"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton2}">
      <Border Background="Transparent">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="Click to navigate to external content2" />
          <Button Content="Link" 
                  Command="{Binding NavigateToUrlCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="https://stackoverflow.com" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </Popup>
    <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2" />
  </StackPanel>

  <Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger SourceName="Window"
                  RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.PreviewMouseUp">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToolTip1"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                     Value="False" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToolTip2"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                     Value="False" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>

    <EventTrigger SourceName="RadioButton1"
                  RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.MouseEnter">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToolTip1"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                     Value="True" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToolTip2"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                     Value="False" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger SourceName="RadioButton2"
                  RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.MouseEnter">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToolTip2"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                     Value="True" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ToolTip1"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                     Value="False" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Window.Triggers>
</Window>
```